# typeof(T) vs. Object.GetType() performance

Tags: c#, .net

Is anyone aware of any differences between `typeof(T) where T : struct`, 
for example, vs. `t.GetType() where t is a System.Object`?
ILdasm shows that typeof(T) uses `System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(RuntimeTypeHandle handle)`, and the other is just plain `System.Object::GetType()`.  The implementations are `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]`, 
so the methods are defined in native code in the CLR.  So, I'm just wondering if anyone is aware of any reason to prefer one over the other?

EDIT:  Let me clarify, I'm mostly interested in the cases where it doesn't seem to matter which you choose - that is, is there a performance difference, or any other reason?  Thanks!

Comment: If you know statically (at compile-time) what type you want, use typeof. Otherwise, use GetType() to get it at run-time.

Comment: I figured that the perf of typeof(T) would be better than Object.GetType(), but really, it is probably totally insignificant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

Comment: I suspect that Object::GetType() just does a Type::GetTypeFromHandle after it finds the RuntimeTypeHandle in the instance of t. So, typeof may be a tiny bit faster. If you are interested in the performance, you should benchmark it. But for readability/maintainability I think it is better to stick to typeof when you can use it.

Comment: @Amicable Yes, saw all those, I should have put performance in the question title, because that's not addressed by the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @EldritchConundrum Thanks, that's sort of what I was thinking but things go native, so it's tough to say.  I should have asked if anyone has some benchmarks handy on typeof vs. GetType() where everything else is equal.  I've flagged this question for deletion because it's really just become a duplicate.

Comment: So what is your **actual problem**?  [What types of questions should I avoid asking? - You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @ErikPhilips Actual problem is to determine any performance differences to improve performance of my code.  If you want to close it as a duplicate, point to http://stackoverflow.com/a/6417977/1149773 instead of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is.

Comment: Actually, from the duplicates, the answer seems to be, "go benchmark it", or "nobody knows or cares". ;)

Comment: @RichardHein: Actually, there are some benchmarks by Jon Skeet. I've posted a link below.

Comment: @RichardHein there is no code provided to attempt a solution, so this appears to be preemptive optimization.

Comment: @ErikPhilips The code is var t = typeof(T); vs. var t = t.GetType(), and I provided the IL.  I already voted to close it myself, so as I said, vote to close if you think it really needs more code, but I wouldn't agree with your reasoning that code has to be provided.  Some questions don't require code as questions or answers and I'm pretty sure that's not a requirement of SO.

Comment: Ok, the real answer is here, thanks @Douglas:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/353435/1149773  We can now close this as a duplicate and point to that or whatever.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`typeof` is used when you want to get the `Type` instance representing a specific type. `GetType` gives the runtime type of the object on which it is called, which may be different from the declared type.

For example:

```
class A {}

class B : A {}

class Program
{
    static A CreateA()
    {
        return new B();
    }
 
    static void Main()
    { 
        A a = CreateA();
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(A));     // Writes "A"
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());   // Writes "B"
    }
}
```

In the above case, within the `Main` method, you're dealing with instances of type `A`; thus, if you care about the declared type, you would use `typeof(A)`. However, the `CreateA` method actually returns an instance of a derived class, `B`, despite declaring the base class as the return type. If you want to find out about this runtime type, call `GetType` on the returned instance.

**Edit**: Mehrdad's comment points in the right direction. Although `typeof` emits a `GetTypeFromHandle` call that takes a `RuntimeTypeHandle` as parameter, the said parameter would actually correspond to the specific type whose metadata token is on the evaluation stack. In some instances, this token would be there implicitly (due to the current method invocation); otherwise, it can be pushed there explicitly by calling [ldtoken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldtoken.aspx). You can see more examples of this in these answers:

- [Efficiency of C#'s typeof operator (or whatever its representation is in MSIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6417977/1149773)
- [Generating IL for 2D Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260809/1149773)

**Edit<sub>2</sub>**: If you're looking for performance benchmarks, you can refer to [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/353435/1149773). His results were (for 100 million iterations):

```
typeof(Test):   2756ms
test.GetType(): 3734ms
```

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but then if you look at the IL, typeof(T) generates  class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle) ... that sure appears to be getting the runtime type, no?

Comment: @RichardHein: I think you might be confusing a `RuntimeTypeHandle` with the "run-time type" (a.k.a. "dynamic type") of an object.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yeah, probably.  ;)

Comment: Ah, that's (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6417977/1149773) the duplicate I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Ahhhhh, thanks ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/353435/1149773 is really what I wanted.  Figures that Jon Skeet answered it.  Notice that the question has no downvotes.  The good old days.

Comment: Don't let the downvotes get to you; their effect on reputation is negligible.

Answer (score 4):

Well, sometimes in generic code, you know the compile time type from a type parameter `T`, without having an instance. Then you must use `typeof(T)`.

At other times, typically in non generic code, you might be interested in the runtime type of an object. Then you use `GetType()`.

So in some cases, depending on what you want to know, or what you can query for, you only have one option.

And sometimes, you could choose.

Answer (score 3):

You use typeof when you want compile-time information and GetType when you want runtime information.

If you're in a situation where you can use either, you should use typeof because it can be resolved at compile-time. This makes it clearer what the Type value will be and (in principle) allows more optimizations.

The typeof keyword takes a compile-time type identifier and gives you the corresponding runtime instance of Type:

```
Type intType = typeof(int);
Type stringType = typeof(string);
Type objectType = typeof(object);
Type genericType = typeof(T);

// not permitted: typeof(1), typeof(someVariable)
```

The GetType instance method takes a run-time instance and tells you its exact runtime type:

```
Type intType = 1.GetType(); // typeof(int)
Type objectType = new Object().GetType(); // typeof(object)

object x = "test";
Type stringType = x.GetType(); // typeof(string), NOT typeof(object)

// not permitted: int.GetType(), string.GetType(), T.getType()
```

You typically only need to use typeof or GetType when writing something that does reflection, creating expression trees by hand, or using the terrible Enum methods (which take an instance of Type instead of a generic type parameter).

Answer (score 2):

`GetType()` is used to retrieve the instance type which actually you have but `typeof()` used to get an instance type what you don't have also `GetType()` gets resolved at runtime, while `typeof()` is resolved at compile time.

Comment: `typeof()` is **not** resolved at compile time, it results in a method call.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester is right: typeof() is resolved to a method call. `Type.GetTypeFromHandle(RuntimeTypeHandle handle)`. -1