# SqlProfileProvider: What's the difference between typeof(string) and Type.GetType("System.String") in SettingsProperty?

Tags: c#, types, profile

I was writing a custom profile provider and had to handle data coming from WCF. Now basically my Profile Provider makes a bridge over WCF to another Profile Provider and I was implementing the `GetPropertyValues`. Since a `SettingsPropertyCollection` cannot be serialized I created a simple custom class to communicate my desired profile properties:

```
[DataContract]
public class ProfileKey
{
    public ProfileKey()
    {
    }

    public ProfileKey(string name, string type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

So to get the profile values I would send a list of ProfileKeys and a SettingsProperty has 2 important properties to get a profile property from the standard `SqlProfileProvider` which was being used behind the WCF service: Name and Type. Having to build the SettingsPropertyCollection myself on the WCF side seemed like no issue like this:

```
SettingsPropertyCollection properties = new SettingsPropertyCollection();
foreach (ProfileKey key in collection)
{
    properties.Add(new SettingsProperty(key.Name) { PropertyType = Type.GetType(key.Type) });
}
```

To my big surprise the above code did not work! After a lot of experimentation I found that it only works when I use `typeof(string)` instead. Flabbergasted by this I ran the following in the immediate window: `typeof(string) == Type.GetType("System.String")` and the result was indeed `true`?

**So my question is what is the difference between `typeof(string)` and `Type.GetType("System.String")` and if they are indeed equal why doesn't the `SqlProfileProvider` return my values when using the later?**

This other question may look similar: [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)

However, the present question is not about the performance of typeof vs GetType neither does the answer to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is) answer why `typeof(string) == GetType("System.String")` results in a TRUE and the SqlProfileProvider will only work for the typeof(string) Type.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17495443/745969

Comment: Your test showed that the **results** were  equal, not the functions themselves. That comparison should return false.

Comment: Just to make sure, `key.Type` is really `"System.String"` for all keys?

Comment: Yes all keys are System.String (for now) that's why as temporary workaround I have placed typeof(string) to have code work. But in the near future we're planning on adding different profile properties that are not string.