# Importance of getting resolved at run-time or compile-time for .GetType () and Typeof () in c#

Tags: c#, types

I recently read and article about .GetType () and Typeof () methods in c#. Now, I know that both of them return System. Type. That article also indicated that it's important to know .GetType () gets resolved at run-time while the other one does at compile-time.

I wonder why it should be considered this fact? Having in mind that the return value of both functions is the same, why we need to know 'when' they get resolved?

Thank you

Comment: "Having in mind that the return value of both functions is the same"? This is very confusing statement - usually one would expect such comparison for methods that called on the same kind of objects and  take same arguments which is absolutely not the case here. Could you please show an example that demonstrate that?

Comment: `typeof` is faster - since more can be done at compile time. I suppose that might be relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495402/typeoft-vs-object-gettype-performance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`typeof` isn't a method - it's an *operator*. That's how it's resolved at compile time. They don't do the same thing, in that for `typeof` you need to know the actual type or type parameter<sup>1</sup> you want at compile-time, whereas for `GetType` you don't. For example:

```
Stream x = GetStreamFromSomewhere();
Type t1 = typeof(Stream); // Always exactly System.IO.Stream
Type t2 = x.GetType();    // Never System.IO.Stream
```

`t2` can never be `System.IO.Stream`, because that's an abstract type. It could be `System.IO.MemoryStream`, `System.IO.FileStream`, or some kind of stream subclass that didn't even exist when I wrote this code. It's the type of the *actual object* that the value of `x` refers to. That will always be a stream of *some* kind, but we don't know until we ask what the type actually is.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're using `typeof(T)` then the actual type isn't know by that piece of code at compile-time, but it's the type argument for any particular call. It's not using the execution-time type of a particular object.

Comment: alright, you beat me by 30s...I have to type faster :D

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thank you. So, 'why' it is important to know it? In other words, how this fact can affect our code? Would you please give and example by a piece of code?

Comment: @TheeSunnLightt: Well when are you thinking of calling `GetType()`, and when are you thinking of using `typeof`? You might want to use `GetType()` to log the actual type of a parameter value for example, whereas `typeof` can be particularly useful for generic methods where you've got a generic type parameter and you want to know the type argument...

Comment: Nitpicking here, I know, but "*you need to know the actual type you want at compile-time*" is misleading. The *compiler* needs to know, not necessarily you; in`typeof(T)` you dont know what types `T` will be. Theoretically, if generics is correctly used, `T` can be infinite different types.

Comment: @InBetween: Will clarify that.

Comment: @InBetween That's not just nitpicking. This actually defies the article's statement that typeof() is evaluated at compile-time. Clearly this is not true when using generic types. Does anyone know if typeof() is evaluated at compile-type for non-generic types at least, thus optimizing by 'hard-coding' the type? Or whether typeof() always is evaluated at run-time, even though it retrieves the compile-time type. Searching for the answer, I stumbled upon this question.